# How can I append a value from the database to an anchor tag's href attribute?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, attributes

I am using a popup jquery that pops up a static block of code using a href=#?w=300?h=200 but I need apart from the size to pass a variable from a sql database also  a href=?prop_id=$id . I have tried to combine both of them but nothing seems to work does anybody has a clue??

thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {



//When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

    //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
    var query= popURL.split('?');
    var dim= query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="to_use/close.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    //Fade in Background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies 

    return false;
});

//Close Popups and Fade Layer
$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
    });
    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Usually you would use `a href=#?w=300&h=200&propId=something`. This is also what you seem to do in the script. You find the query by splitting on `?` and then get each of the query strings by splitting `&`.

Comment: thanx for the reply but i have already used that the thing is that it pops up but the value of the variable is not passing through ...

Comment: what does `"tried to combine both of them"` mean? Post sample html with all href values in it

Comment: hi there I meant that I combined the variables in order to pass them and the width and height but the pop up window pops but the variables can't pass through i will post the whole code so if you have the time to check it out 

<a href=\"#?w=300&h=200?propId=$id \" class=\"poplight\" rel=\"popup_name\" > click here </a>

the popup:

Comment: <? 
  $instructor_id = $_GET['propId'];
   
 $t_results = mysql_query("select * from $tbl_athl, $tbl_instruct where $tbl_athl.ath_id = $tbl_instruct.prop_athlima and $tbl_instruct.prop_id =  $instructor_id ") or die ("cannot select from instructors");
 

  while($t_obj = mysql_fetch_array($t_results)) {
     
  $id = $t_obj['prop_id'];
  $name = $t_obj['prop_name'];
  $athlima = $t_obj['athlima'];
  $path = $t_obj['prop_photo'];
  $cv=$t_obj['prop_cv'];

Comment: echo " <div style=\"width:220px; float:left;\">
  
     <div style=\"width:200px; height:250px; margin:auto; overflow:hidden; \"><img src=\"$path\"  /></div> <br/><br />
  <div style=\"width:200px; margin:auto\">name:$name </div>
  <div style=\"width:200px; margin:auto\">sport:$athlima </div> 
  </div> 
 
 <div style=\"width:720px; float:left; margin-left:230px; position:absolute\">
 <div style=\"width:200px;\">bio: $cv</div></div>
  
  <br/> ";
   
  
  
 }  
  ?>

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to use `data-` attributes in combination with [jQuery's .data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

HTML

```
 <a href="#" class="poplight" data-propId="123" data-w="300" data-h="200">Text</a>
```

JS

```
   /* in click handler */
  var data=$(this).data();
  var propId=data.propId;/* same as $(this).data('propId') */
  var popWidth=data.w;
   /* etc..*/
```

Comment: hi thank you for the reply, but just to be clear
in the js i add the above code or i add the code and delete 
the variables dim query and popWidth? because i tried both ways and is still not working. It's just reload the page.. do you have any idea?
thank you again